# Using RegEx how can I match a pattern of letter number letter in a string in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is an example:

```
var string = "ad1p"
var string1 = "1sdc"
```

expression would match string but not string1

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
var matches = string.match(/[a-z]\d[a-z]/i);
```

[Here's a demo](https://regex101.com/r/gX3pM1/1).